# On git checkout branch I see updating files (900/112987)

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a very large repository 7.1 GB of files. I am getting two different behaviors on two different vm's for the same repository.
When I do a git checkout branch on 1 vm it switches right away. On the other vm when I do git checkout branch I get updating files (90/113987) and it takes forever. How can I stop this and just switch like the other vm?

Comment: Probably there's configuration to change the EOL format of files in one of the VMs (which would potencially mean modifying a lot of files during checkout). Check the value of `core.autocrlf` of both.

Comment: There are multiple possible reasons for this. We need a lot more information about the setup. (The EOL-modification is certainly one possible reason, but others include: where the index is located, where the work-tree is located, how the VM's file systems are provided, and so on.)